# php warning when logging in website folder by cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, web-config

I am writing some php script in the cpanel. When I access the website folder
(e.g. www.bbbbbb.com/folder/) 
It give the warning like that.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host    'host07.portalwebhosting' (1) in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/variables/variables.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli::set_charset() [mysqli.set-charset]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/includes/connect_database.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli::stmt_init() [mysqli.stmt-init]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/includes/login_form.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/includes/login_form.php on line 46
```

And I use the default account admin to access, it gives me the same result.

And here is my php coding

```
<?php
// database configuration
$host ="host07.portalwebhosting.com";
$user ="user";
$pass ="password";
$database = "monkey";
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$database) or die("Error :    ".mysql_error());

// access key to access API
$access_key = "12345";?>
```

Comment: Is `host07.portalwebhosting.com` accessible from the outside? Aka did you open some ports and set some MySQL settings? Why not use `localhost` as host?

Comment: I get a donmain and hosting in host07.portalwebhosting.com
But how can I test the accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your connection string or may be you need to try with port

```
$connection = new mysqli("host", "user", "pwd", "db", "3306");
```

no need to change port 3306 is default
why you use  `die("Error :    ".mysql_error());` use mysqli

Comment: Do you mean I replace this sentence to the below one
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$database) or die("Error :    ".mysql_error());

Comment: p.s: I am using Cpanel in this case

Comment: How can I know the port number?

Comment: add 3306 it's default

Comment: I get the similar error Warning: 

mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'host' (1) in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/variables/variables.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/includes/connect_database.php on line 3

Comment: you need to contact your host provider

Comment: I am just follow the installing guideline of an application, however, the problem comes out

Comment: as Rakesh pointed out, you should contact your host provider. to find your port number in cpanel, go to phpMyAdmin, then the variables tab and scroll down to port and that will tell you which port you're using